# Facebook Login Independent from Native iOS

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-login

I am trying to figure out how I can have a Facebook login within my app that is completely separate from any Facebook account logged in to the device somewhere else.

I would like to be able to switch Facebook accounts within my app while keeping the iPad owners Facebook account associated natively with the device. Is this possible?

I know it's not going to just be simple code, since I basically want to bypass the native Facebook sdk login.

Comment: I think you'd have to use the FaceBook SDK (and not the Apple iOS one)...

Comment: The Facebook SDK still jumps to the Facebook app or Safari for the login so that doesn't work either.